# How can I show html object that is behind a fixed element?

Tags: html, css

I have created a top navigation with these styles below:

```
div.topnav
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And I want to render a 



 object, but that is being displayed behind my top bar, check it out on the image below:

[image: P behind the Topbar]

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Hi, there, Max! Welcome to stack overflow. Your current question does not provide enough information for the community to help you out. I suggest you take a look at this since you are new here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the image you provided I believe that what is happening is that your `<p>` is being rendered behind your *topbar*

if you add something like:

```
p {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

you should be able to see it!

I'm using 60 because it would be 50 from the topbar height + 10 for a small padding

Comment: Thank you, but I put padding-top instead margin-top. Because with margin-top for some reason all my top nav goes down with <p>

Comment: Glad to be helpful!